# Splitting HTML string with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have a html code like this:

```
<div class="classA">
Content
</div>
<div class="classA">
Content
</div>
 // another ClassA ....

 <div class="classA">
 <blockquote>Some key</blockquote >
 </div>
```

How can I remove outerHTML of `Some key` or get all html code above `class` which had `Some key` with Html agility pack?

It's mean, the result I want is

```
 <div class="classA">
Content
</div>
<div class="classA">
Content
</div>
 // another ClassA ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPATH is your friend.

This returns expected result with just one query

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
   "//blockquote[text()='Some key']/parent::*/preceding::*"))
      Console.WriteLine(node.OuterHtml);
```

where

- `//blockquote[text()='Some key']` selects element with the required key. If it should be within `<div class="classA">`, use more precise path expression of `//div[@class='classA']/blockquote[text()='Some key']`
- `parent` selects parent element, which is `<div class="classA">`
- `preceding` selects all nodes before the given node

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BlQ3w9

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to find the text `Some key`, then look at the parents until you find and element with class `classA` and then remove that element > down in the DOM.

You can find an element by it's inner text: https://html-agility-pack.net/knowledge-base/14288183/find-the-parent-div-of-a-specific-text-in-a-htmldocument

Then you may want to loop parent until `null` or you find a ParentNode.HasClass('classA').  You may also be able to use Linq on Ancestors().

At that point, you have the element you want to remove.  So, you can use that to find siblings AFTER itself and remove them.